# correct configuration path of custom object detection model

Tags: python, object-detection, transfer-learning

I have written an object detection model that uses the `COCO` dataset to detect the 91 different classes of objects. I was curious if I could write a custom object detection model to detect any additional classes that would also be detected. For instance, I trained a custom object detection model to detect two random classes (dog and panda) and wanted to create a Python script that can detect the 91 classes present in the `COCO` dataset and the 2 additional classes for a total of 93-classifier detection model.

```
import cv2
import pyttsx3

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, 640)
cap.set(4, 480)

# Model 1 - Coco Dataset (91 classes)
classNames = []
classFile = 'coco.names'
with open(classFile,'rt') as f:
    classNames = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
# Found documentation for SSD mobilenet V3
configPath = 'ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt'
weightsPath = 'frozen_inference_graph_coco.pb'

net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weightsPath, configPath)
net.setInputSize(320, 320)
net.setInputScale(1.0 / 127.5)
net.setInputMean((127.5, 127.5, 127.5))
net.setInputSwapRB(True)


# Model 2 - 2 classifier Model dog and panda
classNames2 = []
classFile2 = 'coco.names2' #this file contains 1. dog and 2. panda
with open(classFile2,'rt') as f:
    classNames2 = [line.rstrip() for line in f]

configPath2 = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config' # This is where I get the error - I am not sure which configuration path to use
weightsPath2 = 'frozen_inference_graph_dog_panda.pb'

net2 = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weightsPath2, configPath2)
net2.setInputSize(320, 320)
net2.setInputScale(1.0 / 127.5)
net2.setInputMean((127.5, 127.5, 127.5))
net2.setInputSwapRB(True)

engine = pyttsx3.init()
while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img, confThreshold=0.60, nmsThreshold=0.2)
    classIds2, confs2, bbox2 = net2.detect(img, confThreshold=0.60, nmsThreshold=0.2)
    print(classIds, bbox)
    print(classIds2, bbox2)
    if len(classIds2) != 0:
        for classId2, confidence2, box2 in zip(classIds2.flatten(), confs2.flatten(), bbox2):
        className2 = classNames2[classId2 - 1]
        str2 = str(className2)
        print(str2)
        engine.say(str2 + "detected")
        engine.runAndWait()
    continue
if len(classIds) != 0:
    for classId, confidence, box in zip(classIds.flatten(), confs.flatten(), bbox):
        className = classNames[classId - 1]
        str1 = str(className)
        print(str1)
        engine.say(str1 + "detected")
        engine.runAndWait()
    continue
if len(classIds and classIds2) == 0:
    engine.say("no objects detected")
    engine.runAndWait()
    continue
cv2.imshow('Output', img)
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

My Error:

```
/Users/venuchannarayappa/PycharmProjects/ObjectDetector/venv/bin/python /Users/venuchannarayappa/PycharmProjects/ObjectDetector/Custom_Object_Detection_Voice_Feedback.py

[ERROR:0] global /Users/runner/work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp (3554) getLayerShapesRecursively OPENCV/DNN: []:(_input): getMemoryShapes() throws exception. inputs=1 outputs=0/0 blobs=0

[ERROR:0] global /Users/runner/work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp (3557) getLayerShapesRecursively     input[0] = [ 1 3 300 300 ]

[ERROR:0] global /Users/runner/work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp (3567) getLayerShapesRecursively Exception message: OpenCV(4.5.4) /Users/runner/work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp:795: error: (-215:Assertion failed) inputs.size() == requiredOutputs in function 'getMemoryShapes'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/venuchannarayappa/PycharmProjects/ObjectDetector/Custom_Object_Detection_Voice_Feedback.py", line 43, in <module>
    classIds2, confs2, bbox2 = net2.detect(img, confThreshold=0.60, nmsThreshold=0.2)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4) /Users/runner/work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp:795: error: (-215:Assertion failed) inputs.size() == requiredOutputs in function 'getMemoryShapes
```

Process finished with exit code 1.

Here is a link to the files that I used to create my custom object detection model:

https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/0c9q7nxUN4bceeLg29XY157cw#my_model

Please help me in determining how to set the configuration path. I believe the .config file of the `SSD Mobilenet V1` should be used but I keep getting a memory shape error.

Also, I have tried changing `net.setInputSize(320, 320)` -> `net.setInputSize(300, 300)`. This change gave me the same error.

Finally, I also tried using the same configuration and weights path for the `COCO` dataset (

```
configPath = 'ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt'
weightsPath = 'frozen_inference_graph_coco.pb
```

both times) and the code runs properly. I believe this means the code is functional but there is some shape error when I use my own frozen inference graph with any .config or .pbtxt file.

If anyone is able to train their own custom model, they would need to change the 'coco.names' file to display the correct classes and input the configuration and weights path. I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Sure thing I just put the entire error message in the response.